# f# type providers and INPC metaprogramming

Tags: f#, inotifypropertychanged, type-providers

I read the following article

http://studentguru.gr/b/kron/archive/2012/09/26/c-template-metaprogramming-and-f-type-providers.aspx

which shows a way to do compile time Fibonacci sequence generation with F# Type providers. The solution is in the article but the final program is

```
> cat .\fib.fs
type fib = Playground.StaticFibonacci<100000>
printfn "Fibonacci(100000) has %d digits" fib.Value.Length
> fsc .\fib.fs -o fib.exe -r:.\FibonacciTypeProvider.dll –nologo
> .\fib.exe
Fibonacci(100000) has 20899 digits
```

This look very powerful. I was wondering if it would be possible to create a type provider for INPC ( INotifyPropertyChanged ) such that you instead of

```
open System.ComponentModel

type MyObject() =
    let mutable propval = 0.0

    let propertyChanged = Event<_, _>()
    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<clievent>]
        member x.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    member this.MyProperty
        with get() = propval
        and  set(v) =
            propval <- v
            propertyChanged.Trigger(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"))
```

You might be able to write

```
open System.ComponentModel

type MyObject() =
    let mutable propval = 0.0

    let propertyChanged = Event<_, _>()
    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<clievent>]
        member x.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    member this.MyProperty : INPCTypeProvider<double>
```

So before I waste half a day digging into this perhaps somebody more informed could tell me I am wasting my time and this level of meta programming is just not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how do you want this to behave. Type providers can be used to generate types at compile time based on your code. How would generating a type help you here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think you can achieve this with F# type providers (but I can see that that it would be nice). There is a number of problems and thoughts I can think of:

- In your example, your `INPCTypeProvider<double>` would have to return something like a representation of a "property". This is not possible, because properties are not first-class values (unlike events). If they were, you wouldn't need a type provider...
- Type provider cannot be parameterized by an existing type, so you cannot write say:

  ```
  type MyNotifyObject = ProvideNotifiable<MyObject>
  ```

  If this was possible, `ProvideNotifiable` could be a provider taking a type and building a new type with additional interface implementation. But this is not possible at the moment.
- If you only need simple types, you might be able to create something like:

  ```
  type MyObject = ProvideNotifiable<"MyProperty:int, OtherProperty:string">
  ```

  This could generate a type with the two properties (defined in the string), but you cannot add anything more to the generated type (although, you might be able to generate actual type using *generative provider* and inherit from it...) I think this is probably the best you can do.

Aside from type providers, you can simplify the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` a bit by using quotations. This [F# snippet gives a simple example](http://fssnip.net/4Q) that makes the implementation safer.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Does f# have the ability to have the membername parameter decorator so you can do away with the code quotation?

Comment: Recently a github repo has been created to try and solve this problem.  https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/fsharp-wpf-mvc-series/wiki/INotifyPropertyChanged-Type-Provider